# Apply CSS to header instand of div

Tags: jquery, css

I have a very advanced header to select content. For the content I want to apply different colors to the header depending on the row it belongs to.

I'm quite close atm; it gives a border-bottom at the div instead of the header.

rows is the number of row, 12 for example.
getRowColor(i) gives me a hex color, and since that color appears the bottom of the div it should work.

```js
function setCSSColors() {
  // set headlines correct color
  var blockIncrement = 1 / rows;

  for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var min = i * blockIncrement,
        max = (i + 1) * blockIncrement
    ;

    // sloppy fix
    if(min > 0) {
      min += 0.00000001;
    }

    $(".headline").filter(
      function() {
        return parseFloat( $(this).attr("data-rating") ) >= min &&
               parseFloat( $(this).attr("data-rating") ) <= max
        ;
      }
    ).each(
      function() {
        // console.log( $(this) );

        // getRowColor here instand of red
        $(this).css( "border-bottom", "2px solid " + getRowColor(i) + "" );

        // $("h1").css( "border-bottom", "2px solid " + getRowColor(i) + "" );
        // $(this).children.("h1").css( "border-bottom", "2px solid " + getRowColor(i) + "" );
        console.log( getRowColor(i) );
      }
    );

  }
}
```

Only everything else I try results in no CSS applied.

some html of it:

```
<div class="headline" data-rating="0.482005543693" onclick="javascript:showArticle(1076);" style="display: none; ">
                        <div class="headline_txt"><h1>#3726: Meryl Streep schittert in The Iron Lady- alle recensies op een rijtje</h1></div>                       <div class="preview_txt"><p>De eerste foto's van actrice Meryl Streep als de Britse voormalig premier Margaret Thatcher <a href="http://www.guardian.co.uk/film/2011/feb/08/meryl-streep-margaret-thatcher-iron-lady#">leidden</a> vorig jaar al tot een stortvloed aan publiciteit. Nu is <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1007029/"><em>The Iron Lady</em></a> er dan ook echt. Vanaf vandaag draait de film in de Nederlandse bioscopen. Lees hier alle recensies.<!--more--></p></div>                  </div>
```

Comment: some html of the div would be cool.

Comment: Even cooler is if you could put your JS, CSS, and markup in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us.

Comment: Also, is `getRowColor` returning what you expect it to?

Comment: edited my post, rows have a int value, getRowColor is returning what i expect. Aslo the project is quite complex and uses a lot of resources so fiddle is not really great for it.

Comment: @clankill3r: Part of solving a problem is **identifying** and  **isolating** it, and posting a minimal demo on jsfiddle can sometimes by itself help you solve your problem (or at least help you work on it).

Comment: just curious

Why you put quotes marks at the end of this line? [... + "");]:


$(this).css( "border-bottom", "2px solid " + getRowColor(i) + "" );

Comment: First you need to determine exactly which elements should have a style applied (or a css class added), because I think you are targeting the wrong items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's a bit hard to understand which exact elements should be coloured, I think you probably want to target the `h1` element inside the `div` instead of the `div` itself.

You can do that by changing

`$(this).css( "border-bottom", "2px solid " + getRowColor(i) + "" );`

into

`$(this).find('h1').css( "border-bottom", "2px solid " + getRowColor(i) + "" );`

That targets all `h1` elements inside the `divs` (not just the first one).